# In a nested array of objects and using a value of key 1, get the value of key 2

Tags: javascript

I have a json file of folders.

**folders.json**

```json
[
    {
      "name": "Documents",
      "files": [
        {
          "name": "Quarterly Results",
          "type": "Document"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Favourites",
      "files": [
        {
          "name": "Brawl Stars",
          "files": [
            {
              "name": "NS dying in 5 seconds",
              "type": "Video"
            },
            {
              "name": "Josiah raping NS",
              "type": "Video"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Coding",
          "files": [
            {
              "name": "Coding is so fun",
              "type": "Image"
            },
            {
              "name": "I love svelte",
              "files": [
                {
                  "name": "REPLs",
                  "files": [
                    {
                      "name": "REPL 1",
                      "type": "Image"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "REPL 2",
                      "type": "Videp"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "oh nooo",
                  "type": "Document"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Favourites 1",
          "type": "Document"
        },
        {
          "name": "Favourites 2",
          "type": "Video"
        },
        {
          "name": "Favourites 3",
          "type": "Image"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Knowledge Base 1",
      "type": "Video"
    }
  ]
```

Let's say I have the folder "name" in folders.json. I want to find all file names inside it.

For example, given a folder "Favourites", I want to output:

```js
[{name: 'Brawl Stars', files: Array(2)}, {name: 'Coding', files: Array(2)} {"name": "Favourites 1", "type": "Document"}, {"name": "Favourites 2","type": "Video"},{"name": "Favourites 3", "type": "Image"}]
```

Note: A folder is when there are `files` inside the same dictionary as `name`.

Thus, using a value of key: `name`, output out the values of `files` in this nested array of objects.

I have tried the following: `root.filter(item => item.name === currentFolder).map(item => item.files)`, where root is the array of objects, currentFolder is the folder "name" in folder.json.

However, this only works for depth of 2, where the folder is not nested in other folders.

I have tried looking for other answers, but all other answers only work for until depth of 2, thus needing help.

I am currently using sveltekit framework, not using jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some recursion. Loop over every folder, and return the folder if it is what we want. Otherwise, do the same process for that folder. Just like this:

```js
function getFolder(folders, name) {
  for (const folder of folders) {
    // skip if this isn't a folder
    if (!folder.files) continue;
    // if this folder is what we're looking for, then return
    if (folder.name === name) return folder;
    
    // else recurse and return if we get a result
    const subsearch = getFolder(folder.files, name);
    if (subsearch) return subsearch;
  }
  // if there's no matches, return null
  return null
}

const folders = [{name:"Documents",files:[{name:"Quarterly Results",type:"Document"}]},{name:"Favourites",files:[{name:"Brawl Stars",files:[{name:"NS dying in 5 seconds",type:"Video"},{name:"Josiah raping NS",type:"Video"}]},{name:"Coding",files:[{name:"Coding is so fun",type:"Image"},{name:"I love svelte",files:[{name:"REPLs",files:[{name:"REPL 1",type:"Image"},{name:"REPL 2",type:"Videp"}]},{name:"oh nooo",type:"Document"}]}]},{name:"Favourites 1",type:"Document"},{name:"Favourites 2",type:"Video"},{name:"Favourites 3",type:"Image"}]},{name:"Knowledge Base 1",type:"Video"}];

console.log(getFolder(folders, 'Favourites'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use recursion when you search multiple layers of nested data.

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336281/javascript-find-by-value-deep-in-a-nested-object-array)

```
function findNested(obj, key, value) {
    // Base case
    if (obj[key] === value) {
        return obj;
    } else {
        var keys = Object.keys(obj); // add this line to iterate over the keys

        for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
            var k = keys[i]; // use this key for iteration, instead of index "i"

            // add "obj[k] &&" to ignore null values
            if (obj[k] && typeof obj[k] == "object") {
                var found = findNested(obj[k], key, value);
            if (found) {
                // If the object was found in the recursive call, bubble it up.
                return found;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then you can just do this: (where 'folders' is your data)

```
findNested(folders, "name", "REPLs").files
```